# javascript - API google marker

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a very big problem, I've tried to include this javascript on my web-site... but... It doesn't work... and... I don't know why, somebody can help me ??

```
var map;
var places = [
    ['ferrara1', 44.831283, 11.617459, 'Ha funzionato ?'],
    ['ferrara2', 44.833283, 11.617459, 'se vedo tutto siiii !'],
    ['ferrara3', 44.886283, 11.617459, 'uahahahah'],
    ['ferrara4', 44.832283, 11.617459, 'è vivo'],
];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'),mapOptions);                
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: 'Tu sei Qui.'
            });
            map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
    point(map,places);
};

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Errore: Geolocalizzazione Fallita.';
    } else {
        var content = 'Errore: Questo browser non supporta la Geolocalizzazione.';
    }
    var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.831283, 11.617459),
        content: content
    };
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
};

function point(map, places){
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
        var azienda = places[i]
        var markerLatlng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(azienda[1], azienda[2]);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: azienda[3]
        });
        var marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerLatlng[i],
            map: map,
            title: azienda[0]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map,marker[i])
        });
    }
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Edit:
I try to include this javascript on one html page on my web-site to show google maps with some markers (I have commented out one),  but it doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why.

The issue seems to be with my function `point` because if i remove it, the rest of the code works and the google map loads fine (but I don't get the marker I want).

I'm not sure how to proceed debugging the code in javascript with my browser.

Comment: I would suggest formatting that and putting it into a fiddle maybe?

Comment: What about this doesn't work? SO doesn't do so well with questions that are vague. Do you have an console errors, for example?

Comment: The code looks fine, do you get any errors? I presume you have a div on your page in the html named 'maps' ?.

Comment: And you've included a link to the google maps API?

Comment: Looks like you've declared the array incorrectly.

var markerLatlng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(azienda[1], azienda[2]);

From the looks you probably don't even need the array.  I.e. var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(azienda[1], azienda[2]);

Comment: I'm new here and I'm still getting the hang of the interface. Sorry for the vague question, planned on editing it and didn't expect replies anytime soon. Editing the post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two instances of improperly declared arrays.
1. var markerLatlng[i] = ...
2. var marker[i] = ...

```
function point(map, places){
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
        var azienda = places[i];
        var markerLatlng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(azienda[1], azienda[2]);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: azienda[3]
        });
        var marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerLatlng[i],
            map: map,
            title: azienda[0]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map,marker[i]);
        });
    }
};
```

Either declare those arrays before assigning values or in this case you may not need arrays at all.

Declare first:

```
var markerLatLng = [], markers = [];

function point(map, places){
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
        var azienda = places[i];
        markerLatlng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(azienda[1], azienda[2]);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: azienda[3]
        });
        marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerLatlng[i],
            map: map,
            title: azienda[0]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map,marker[i]);
        });
    }
};
```

No arrays:

```
function point(map, places){
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
        var azienda = places[i];
        var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(azienda[1], azienda[2]);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: azienda[3]
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: azienda[0]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }
};
```

Edit: adding some more semi-colons for consistency :)